# Binding multiple keys to a function in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, bind

Say if i wish to bind my space bar and the key "w" to any random function in my code, how would i do this? Should i be using if "w" and if "" then perform or can you bind multiple keys to one function?

```
#if statement way. idk how to do this tho
if "w" == Pressed:
   if "<space>" == Pressed:
      #perform function

#or 
self._master.bind("<space>", "w", lambda e: function)
```

Comment: what do you use ? `tkinter`, `PyQt`, `PySide`, `wxPython`, other ?

Comment: I am currently using tkinter in python to perform this function

Comment: then put this information in question so other people could see it.

Comment: apologies. i am new to using stack exchange.

Answer (score 4):

In `tkinter` you can put string with all keys `"<space>w"` and you can do: press space, (release space or not), press `w` and it will run function.

```
import tkinter as tk

def test(event):
    print('test')

root = tk.Tk()

root.bind('<space>w', test)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me (tkinter 8.4, Python 3.9). It does just nothing. It gives no error message and does not call the handling function `funct`. The `root.bind('<Left><Right>c', funct)` is just ignored and has no effect. If I spilt it into three lines with three `.bind()` commands it works ok.

Comment: @Claudio it works for me on Linux Mint, Python 3.8, tk/tcl 8.6. But it need to press keys in correct order - first `Left`, next `Right`, and finally `c`. If I try to press in different order then it doesn't detect it.

Comment: The question was: *Can you bind multiple keys to one function?*. The answer is: *No, you can't do it within one bind() command* right? Your answer points though to the possibility to capture an exact sequence of keys as specified, right? OK ... I have tested it and detected a *side effect* of such a multiple key binding which is that the last key in  the sequence isn't captured by the key-press handler for single key-presses because this key is 'swallowed' by the handler of the key-sequence.

Comment: @Claudio original question at the top was about sequence `<space>w` , not single keys `<space>` or `w`- so I expected that you also ask for sequence `<Left><Right>c`. And if you want to bind single keys `<Left`>` or `<Right>` or `c` then you can't do it in one bind. And you can't do it in other frameworks, and in other languages. Every key or sequence need separated `bind`. Frankly, this was so obviouse for me so I didn't expect that you want to bind seprated keys in one bind.

Comment: *Say if i wish to bind my space bar* **and** *the key "w" to function,* means for me, that you can choose between both keys to achieve the same result. The provided code  is maybe a hint toward a **sequence** of keys. By the way: I just realized there is a third way of understanding possible: if both keys space and w are simultaneously in the pressed state an event is expected to be fired. The question seem to express confusion of its author how to describe what is desired to achieve and the OP seems not to be interested in clarifying it.

Comment: @Claudio if you want to choose between keys then you have to use two `bind()` - single `bind()` is for single key or single sequence. And probably in all frameworks in all languages you have to also use two binds. And in original code OP uses two nested `if` which shows that it want sequence - OP wants to press `space` when `w` is already pressed.

Answer (score -1):

By just adding the and, I was able to bind this Text entry box to both the tab and enter keys. I suppose if you wanted each key to run a different function, you could.

```
Text.bind("<Tab>", AddText) and Text.bind("<Return>", AddText)
```

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, and you shouldn't be using and like that

Comment: The `and` between the `.bind()` commands makes no sense. Use semicolon `;` or put the two commands in two lines.