# Tkinter binding combination of key and mouse

Tags: tkinter, bind

I am new to tkinter and now working with binding functions to keys or mouse clicks. I am trying to trigger a function with a combination of holding down a key on the keyboard and then pressing a Button-1. Doing a bind with "<c><Button-1>" is not working. Please help.

```
class PyViz:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.geometry("1000x500")
        self.frame = Frame(self.window, width=2000, height=1000)
        self.frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        self.canvas = Canvas(
            self.frame,
            width=2000,
            height=1000,
            bg="#FAE6FA",
            scrollregion=(0, 0, 1000, 1000),
        )

        self.motion = Motion(
            window=self.window,
            canvas=self.canvas,
            boxes=self.boxes,
            connections=self.connections,
        )

        self.bind_keys()

        self.window.mainloop()

    def bind_keys(self):
        self.window.bind("c <Button-1>", self.motion.add_class_with_click)
        self.window.bind("<KeyPress-c> <a>", self.motion.add_class)

class Motion:
    def __init__(self, window, canvas, boxes, connections) -> None:
        self.window = window
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.boxes = boxes
        self.connections = connections

    def add_class(self, event):
        """
        green rectangle
        """

        rect_uuid = str(uuid.uuid4())
        new_rect = Box(color="#98FB98", pos=(10, 10), id=rect_uuid)
        new_rect.create_box(self.canvas)
        self.boxes["class"].setdefault(rect_uuid, new_rect)
        print(self.boxes)

    def add_class_with_click(self, event):
        """
        green rectangle
        """
        print("pressed")
        self.add_class(event)

    def add_method(self):
        """
        orange rectangle
        """
        pass
```

This is the code I am dealing with. I am trying to bind the key c and button-1 to a function. The answer's example works when I run it but for some reason the solution doesn't work when used here.

Comment: Which keys, specificly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binding multiple keys to a function in Tkinter Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56204344/binding-multiple-keys-to-a-function-in-tkinter-python)

Answer (score 0):

To bind multiple keys, specify each one at a time, in order.

For example, to bind the "a" key then the button click, you will do `root.bind("a <Button-1>", func)`.

In your question, you wanted to bind any key + mouse click. To do this, use `root.bind("<Key> <Button-1>")`:

```
from tkinter import *


def pressed(a):
    print("Pressed")


root = Tk()

root.bind("<Key> <Button-1>", pressed)
root.mainloop()
```